# Testing ssis12 packages in VS 13, and the packages keep being upgraded against my will

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, ssis

So I am attempting to run SSIS packages that were developed with SQL2012, in VS13. Whenever I attempt to run the package it pops up saying that the package was upgraded. I have confirmed this upgrade by observing a change in the "PackageFormatVersion" in a text editor.

I have found this solution from microsoft: In the property pages for an Integration Services project, on the General tab of Configuration Properties, select the TargetServerVersion property and choose SQL Server 2016, SQL Server 2014, or SQL Server 2012.

However, when i click on my property pages I do not have a general tab (or any place that has an option to select which version of sql server i am using).

I have included an image of what my property pages look like. Also it is a dtproj file that I am using.

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iTbs.jpg)

Comment: It sounds like you issue isn't the SQL2012 it is the version of Visual Studio the packages were developed with which was likely VS2012 now that you are using VS2013 it will convert them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the Visual Studio 2015 editor allows you to specify whether your integration services project is built upon the SQL Server 2012, SQL Server 2014 or SQL Server 2016 technology.

Using any up version tooling results in the package being upgraded in place. So, what you are experiencing is normal.

If you have a full installation of SQL Server on your machine, you can run the packages from the commandline and while they will still upgrade to run, that upgrade will only be in memory and the original file on disk will remain at the earlier version.

On the SQL Server installation media, you need to specify that you want Integration Services Service installed. That is the only way to run SSIS packages outside of Visual Studio/SSDT.

Comment: Thanks, yea i eventually just downloaded all of the past VS's to test them that way. I need to make sure that they run in their intended environment, as many of our customers still use those products. I appreciate the help though!

Comment: For future development, take a look at [Biml](http://varigence.com/biml). You can express your SSIS package in an XML dialect that is version agnostic. This means the solution that loads all the CSVs into the database works whether you have 2005 or 2016. Just open the biml file in the correct version of Visual Studio right click on the biml file and out comes a version correct SSIS package. It's the bees knees